# Navigation Drawer Menu method that gets called everytime it's opened?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm attempting to refresh my current logged in user using the Parse.com framework, and update a label everytime the Navigation Drawer menu is opened. Unfortunately I cannot figure out which method is called every time it's opened to do so. I've tried doing this in the NavigationDrawerAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (listofItems.get(position) instanceof NavigationDrawerListItem) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_item, null);

        return convertView;
    } else if (listofItems.get(position) instanceof NavigationDrawerUserInformation) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_object, null);

        final TextView userName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtvDrawerFirstItemText1);

        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(
                new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(user)) {

                                userName.setText("Welcome Guest");

                            } else {
                                userName.setText("Welcome, "
                                        + user.getUsername() + "!");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        return convertView;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the label is never updated with new information unless I navigate away from the current fragment by clicking another in the menu and open the menu again. Each item in the list is just a new fragment which all opens up in the same Activity.

Comment: have you looked at `DrawerListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html

Comment: Yes and I tried just using the fetchInBackground there without setting the username Text, because I was unsure how to do so if this is the NavigationAdapter my layouts defined in, and those methods would be on my Activity. I assume that didn't work because maybe the fetchInBackground wasn't done loading yet before the adapters set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the drawer the below method gets called:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
```

When you close the drawer the below method gets called:

```
public void onDrawerClosed (View drawerView)
```